# In ATG, can I use Markers as qualifiers for promotions?

Tags: atg, commerce, promotions

Markers (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGCommStoreGuide/html/s1401usingorderandcommerceitemmarkers01.html) provide the ability to tag (almost arbitrary) extra data against Orders and Commerce Items.

Note, in all my years working with ATG, I have never come across their use.

Is it possible to use the presence of a marker as a qualifiers for promotions?

Comment: Haven't heard of them either. Quick scan of the docs suggest they can trigger scenarios. If you can configure a scenario to trigger a promotion, you'll be in luck.

Comment: @radimpe you have seen markers used before: remember something called plus points?? ;-)

Comment: @bated On this project you mention (I seem to recall some repressed memories) I don't believe there was a BCC in play so any promotions would have had to be done manually or perhaps via the ACC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use them as a qualifier for promotions and I have seen them used on a couple of projects. Note that markers can be set for the following repository items:

- Order
- Profile
- CommerceItem

So depending on what the rules for your promotion are you could use markers against 1 or more of the above to trigger different types of promotions e.g. Order for order level promotion or CommerceItem for line level promotion.

[Adding a marker can trigger a scenario](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s2504advancingascenariobasedonprofile01.html) and a scenario can then [trigger your promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s1502scenariobasics01.html).

Comment: Just to clarify; if triggered by a promotion then they cannot be global promotions, but must be personal promotions?

Comment: Correct - if by "global promotion" you mean promotions which are applied automatically by the pricing engine and are available to everyone.